# Convert Apache rewrite to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
​
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
​
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i wanna convert to nginx rewrite rules, i tried with

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
}
```

But it doesn't work, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent rewrite would be:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

As `nginx` URIs include the leading `/` which your script probably does not want. Also, the `.php` file is likely processed in a different location block, so you need to use `last`.

Alternative ways of writing this without the [use of an `if` block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/):

First, with the leading `/`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

Second, without the leading `/`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

All `nginx` directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your .htaccess for nginx. I just switched from Apache 2.4 to Nginx 1.18.0 and it works, but all rewrite lines should be inside your server block in nginx conf, otherwise it converts it all.

https://winginx.com/en/htaccess