# Converting Rules from Apache to Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am quite new with NGINX

Can someone know how to convert the following rules into NGINX?

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
`RewriteRule ^en/(.*) es/$1`

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Apache rewrite to Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736661/convert-apache-rewrite-to-nginx)

Comment: Also: https://serverfault.com/questions/442254/how-do-i-convert-apache-rewrite-rules-to-nginx

Answer (score 0):

[This converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) provides the correct result:

```
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.php;
    rewrite ^/en/(.*) /es/$1;
```